# Error with Image in Customtkinter invalid command name "2721234304896update" while executing

Tags: python, customtkinter

And i had this error, when I close the top level this error apears

```
import customtkinter as ctk

import openpyxl
import os
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def aplicacaoGraficoPareto(localDoArquivo, gerarExel=False):
    localDaImagem = os.path.dirname(localDoArquivo)
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(localDoArquivo, data_only = True)
    sheet = workbook.active

    def pegarExel():
        tipoDefeito = list()
        numeroOcorrencias = list()
        frequecia = list()
        frequeciaAcumulada = list()

        ultimaLinha = 0
        numeroCelula = 2

        while True:
            celula = sheet[f"C{numeroCelula}"].value
            if celula != "Total":
                tipoDefeito.append(celula)
            else:
                ultimaLinha = numeroCelula
                break
            numeroCelula += 1
        
        for numeroOcorrencia in range(2, len(tipoDefeito)+2):
            celula = sheet[f'D{numeroOcorrencia}'].value
            numeroOcorrencias.append(celula)

        for fr in range(2, len(tipoDefeito)+2):
            celula = sheet[f'E{fr}'].value
            frequecia.append(celula * 100)

        for fracum in range(2, len(tipoDefeito)+2):
            celula = sheet[f'F{fracum}'].value
            frequeciaAcumulada.append(celula * 100)


        return tipoDefeito, numeroOcorrencias, frequecia, frequeciaAcumulada, ultimaLinha


    tipo_de_falha, numeroOcorrencias, frequencia, frequeciaAcumulada, ultimaLinha = pegarExel()

    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
    df = pd.DataFrame({'tipo defeito' : tipo_de_falha,
                    'Nº Ocor' : numeroOcorrencias, 
                    'freq (%)': frequencia,
                    'cum (%)' : frequeciaAcumulada})

    fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (12,6))

    ax1.set_title('Pareto')

    color1 = 'tomato'
    #ax1.set_xlabel('X')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Nº Ocorrências',color = color1)

    bars = ax1.bar(df['tipo defeito'], df['Nº Ocor'],color = color1,edgecolor = 'orange',linewidth = 2,\
                    hatch = '*')
    #ax1.set_ylim([-10,10])
    ax1.tick_params(axis = 'y',labelcolor = color1)

    color2 = 'black'
    ax2 = ax1.twinx() # compartilhar o mesmo eixo x
    ax2.set_ylabel('%',color = color2) 

    ax2.plot(df['tipo defeito'], df['cum (%)'],color = color2,marker = 's',markersize = 8, linestyle = '-')

    ax2.tick_params(axis = 'y',labelcolor = color2)
    ax2.set_ylim([0,120])

    for tick in ax1.get_xticklabels():
        tick.set_rotation(90)

    for x, y in zip(df['tipo defeito'], df['cum (%)']):
        ax2.annotate(f'{y:.2f}%', xy=(x, y), xytext=(5, -25), textcoords='offset points',
                    ha='center', fontsize=12)

    plt.savefig(f'{localDaImagem}/Grafico.png',format='png',dpi = 600, bbox_inches = 'tight')

    if gerarExel:
        paretoGrafico = Image(f'{localDaImagem}/Grafico.png')
        paretoGrafico.width = 600
        paretoGrafico.height = 350
        sheet.add_image(paretoGrafico, f"C{ultimaLinha + 3}")
        workbook.save(localDoArquivo)
        subprocess.run(['start', '', localDoArquivo], shell=True)
        return f'{localDaImagem}/Grafico.png'
    else:
        return f'{localDaImagem}/Grafico.png'



def criar_top():
    from PIL import Image

    top_level = ctk.CTkToplevel(janela)

    localDaImagem = aplicacaoGraficoPareto('Loucuras/ParetoExelGrafico/analise.xlsx', False)

    my_image = ctk.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open(localDaImagem),
                                  dark_image=Image.open(localDaImagem),
                                  size=(30, 30))

    image_label = ctk.CTkLabel(top_level, image=my_image, text="")
    image_label.pack()
    top_level.focus_get()

janela = ctk.CTk()

janela.geometry("700x350")
janela.resizable(width=False, height=False)

button = ctk.CTkButton(janela, text="Clique", command=criar_top)
button.pack()

janela.mainloop()
```

I think this error cause by the function aplicacaoGraficoPareto()

invalid command name "2721234304896update"
while executing
"2721234304896update"
("after" script)
invalid command name "2721309552320check_dpi_scaling"
while executing
"2721309552320check_dpi_scaling"
("after" script)